# Where r8.jar is located inside Android SDK?

Tags: java, android, dx, android-d8

I'm trying out Android's [D8 and R8](https://r8.googlesource.com/r8).

As the documentation says the command to run D8 is the following:

```
java -jar build/libs/d8.jar --release --output out input.jar
```

And for R8:

```
java -jar build/libs/r8.jar --release --output out --pg-conf proguard.cfg input.jar
```

I found the `d8.jar` inside `%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\28.0.3\lib`, but I can't find the `r8.jar`.

Where `r8.jar` is located inside Android SDK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the moment, nowhere, unless you plan to build r8 from source. R8 is a new feature currently only available in the [Android Studio 3.3 beta](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/11/r8-new-code-shrinker-from-google-is.html) (3.3 RC2 at the time of writing). By the looks of things it's been baked into Android Studio as well, rather than being left as an external jar, unless they've given it a completely unrelated name. Searching my filesystem didn't yield a single result for `*r8*.jar`.

So if you're using that page as a guide, your easiest bet is to just compile the source as per the instructions and use the resulting `d8.jar` and `r8.jar` files.